# Translate custom transactional email variable

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail, custom-variable

I used this observer: `email_shipment_set_template_vars_before` to add a custom transactional email variable. This is the code from the observer:

```
$transport = $observer->getData('transportObject');
$urlLabel = __('Test');
$transport->setData('customURL', '<a href ="#">'.$urlLabel.'</a>';
```

in my module, in the `i18n/nl_NL.csv` I've added:

```
"Test","Test in NL"
```

However , when I send out the shipment email I still don't get the NL version of my string: **"Test"** . Why ?

This is how I use my custom variable in the email template:

```
{{var customURL|raw}}
```

Any clue what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot!